# Rdlc reporting returns null on renderReport

Tags: c#

I am using c# rdlc reporting I am getting error when it reaches a line on code to generate bytes mimetype is empty  which results in  null exception
can anyone help with this I don't know what I am missing.

```
        string mimeType ="";
        long? plantId = 0;
        LocalReportModel reportModel = new LocalReportModel()
        {
            ExportFileName = "ChangeRequestReportDoc",
            Format = (reportAction == ReportActionType.ExportPDF ? LocalReportFormat.PDF : (reportAction == ReportActionType.ExportExcel ? LocalReportFormat.Excel : LocalReportFormat.Word)),
            Name = "ChangeRequestReportDoc",
            ReportEmbeddedResource = "A.HQM.Reports.ChangeRequestDocument.rdlc"
        };


        if (Cache.LoggedInUserModel() != null)
        {
            var loggedInUser = Cache.LoggedInUserModel();
            plantId = loggedInUser.SelectedPlant;
        }

        TrainingReportFilterModel model = new TrainingReportFilterModel()
        {
            FromDate = fromDate,
            ToDate = toDate,      
            PlantId = plantId
        };


        List<A.HQM.BL.Entities.ChangeRequestData.ChangeRequest> reportData = ChangeRequestProvider.ChangeReport(model.FromDate, model.ToDate, plantId
                                                    ).ToList();


        DataSet dataset = new A.HQM.Reports.ChangeRequest.ChangeRequestData();
        DataTable tableToAdd = dataset.Tables["ChangeRequestReport"];

        foreach (A.HQM.BL.Entities.ChangeRequestData.ChangeRequest found in reportData)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = tableToAdd.NewRow();
            dataRow.SetField("Comments", found.Comments);
            dataRow.SetField("CRSummary",found.CRSummary);
            dataRow.SetField("Status",found.Status);
            dataRow.SetField("ChangeRequestDate", found.ChangeRequestDate);             
            tableToAdd.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        reportModel.DataSets.Add(new LocalReportDataSet() { DataSetData = tableToAdd, DatasetName = "ChangeRequestData" });

        byte[] renderedBytes = reportModel.RenderReport(out mimeType);
        return File(renderedBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, reportModel.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your not passing all required parameters to the `RenderReport` method?

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string filenameExtension;

byte[] renderedBytes = reportModel.RenderReport(
    "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
    out streamids, out warnings);
```

Comment: Great. What is your solution?

Comment: I had the dataset name different from the dataset name on rdlc designer